# Not able to import only S3 directly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, aws-sdk

I am trying to use AWS Javascript SDK, but I am getting some errors.
I am using the latest version of AWS SDK - 2.73.0.

I am not able to use

```
import S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';
```

gives me `S3 undefined`.

Interestingly this works perfectly

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
const S3 = new AWS.S3();
```

But I only want to import S3 not the whole AWS SDK. Any ideas what am i doing wrong.

Comment: what version of aws-sdk are you using?

Comment: AWS_SDK - 2.73.0

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3

const s3 = new AWS({
  apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
  params: {Bucket: process.env.AZ_BUCKETNAME},
});
```

Comment: you cant const S3 = new AWS.S3() if you only imported s3.
Try 
    const S3 = new AWS()